# How do I load sound resource? URLForResource returns nil

Tags: xcode, bundle, assets

I've been following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial) tutorial. This line of code returns nil...

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename as String, withExtension: "caf")
```

Here's my resources...

[image]

Here's my build phase...

[image]

`NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)` doesn't improve the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code worked when I dragged the sound file into the project instead of into the project's asset catalogue. I'm guessing that the latter's items are referenced by id instead of file name and type.

I also needed to add the sound file to the "Copy Bundle Resources" section in "Build Phases".